# python beginner here, recursion code and added the print statement , please explain what print statement is doing here

Tags: python, recursion

My code:

```
def recursive_sum(num):
    if num==0:
        return 0
    result = num + recursive_sum(num- 1) 
    print(recursive_sum(num- 1) , end = " ")
    
    return result
```

recursive_sum(3)

```
0 0 1 0 0 1 3
```

I added the print statement just to play with then this output comes up , it is binary but cant figure out further

Comment: Print num as well to add some additional clarity.

Answer (score 0):

That code prints `0 0 1 0 0 1 3` and return 6. Let's see why, by tracing what happens.

Call recursive_sum(3)

- num=3 is not 0.
- compute `result = 3 + recursive_sum(2)
- to do so Call recursive_sum(2):

  - num=2 is not 0
  - compute `result = 2 + recursive_sum(1)
  - to do so Call recursive_sum(1)

    - num=1 is not 0
    - compute `result = 1 + recursive_sum(0)
    - to do so call recursive_sum(0)

      - num=0 is 0
      - return 0
    - so `result=1+0 = 0`
    - print `recursive_sum(0)`
    - to do so, call recursive_sum(0)

      - num=0 is 0
      - return 0
    - so print argument is 0. **PRINT 0**
    - return result, which is 1.
  - So in this call `result = 2 + recursive_sum(1) = 2 + 1 = 3`
  - print recursive_sum(1)
  - to do so call recursive_sum(1)

    - num=1 is not 0
    - `result = 1 + recursive_sum(0)`
    - to compute that, call recursive_sum(0)

      - num=0 is 0
      - return 0
    - so result = 1+0 = 1
    - print recursive_sum(0)
    - to do so, call recursive_sum(0) [Note, we already know that this returns 0 and print 0. But for this time, I'll redo the trace]

      - num=0 is 0
      - return 0
    - so print argument is 0. **PRINT 0**
    - return result that is 1.
  - argument of print is 1. **PRINT 1**
  - return result, that is 3
- So result = 3 + recursive_sum(2) = 3+3 = 6
- print recursive_sum(2)
- to do so, call recursive_sum(2) [we already know that calling recursive_sum(2) returns 3 and prints "0 0 1"]
- **PRINT 0 0 1** (If you are not conviced, just copy and paste here all the lines from the previous `call recursive_sum(2)` to the `result=` of the same level)
- print argument (recursive_sum(2)) is 3. So **PRINT 3**.
- return result aka 6.

So, long story short: you have a double recursion here. Each call to `recursive_sum` implies two recursive calls, one to compute result, another to print. And both prints things (unless they return 0). I could have summarized things by saying, `recursive_sum(3)` call `recursive_sum(2)` twice. Each `recursive_sum(2)` calls `recursive_sum(1)` twice (so four times altogether). Each `recursive_sum(1)` calls `recursive_sum(0)` twice (but that prints nothing).

Each of the 4 `recursive_call(1)` prints 0. Each of the two `recursive_call(2)` prints 1 (plus what their recursive call prints, that is plus two 0). `recursive_call(3)` prints 3 (plus phat the two `recursive_call(2)` prints). So it is not surprising that displays contains four 0, two 1, and one 3.

And since the two recursive calls of a call are done before it prints something of its own, it is not surprising that the print of 1 by `recursive_call(2)` occurs after the two 0 of its recursive call. And that the two `0 0 1` of the two `recursive_call(2)` occurs before the `3` of `recursive_call(3)`.

Comment: Thanks a lott , I wish my teachers in highschool were like you .

Answer (score 0):

The print statement prints the return values in each iteration.
When you called recursive_sum(3):

> `result = 3 + recursive_sum(2)`
> `result = 2 + recursive_sum(1)`
> `result = 1 + recursive_sum(0)`

In the above three calls, print isn't even reached, now:

```
 *1. recursive_sum(0) returns 0 to recursive_sum(1) via return result
     *2. recursive_sum(1) -> print(recursive_sum(0)) prints 0
     *3. recursive_sum(1) returns 1 to recursive_sum(2) via return result
         *4. recursive_sum(2) -> print(recursive_sum(1)) further calls recursive_sum(0) which returns 0. Hence, it prints 0 1
         *5. recursive_sum(2) returns 3 to recursive_sum(3)
             *6. recursive_sum(3) -> print(recursive_sum(2)) further calls recursive_sum(1) which further calls recursive_sum(0).
             *7. recursive_sum(0) returns 0 so 0 is printed, recursive_sum(1) returns 0 and 1 so 0 and 1 are printed. Now, recursive_sum(2) returned 3, so 0 0 1 3 are printed.
```